how do you unstake VGX token?
i had staked my VGX token through their website back in 2021.
but now their website is no longer available and i have been told that i have to unstake using etherscan. i tried to use the unstake feture under contract--> write contract-->unstake.
i have gone into read contract-->totalStakedFor and used query with my address from my ledger and used the unit256 amount in the unstake feature but i get "Input value cannot be empty".
i have been leaving the data blank as i dont know what goes there.
Any help would be much appreciated
my public address: 0xaB13FFA926D62186cD3F1984c110A055872C014C
Stake contract address: 0x8692E782Ea478623f3342E0FB3936f6530C5d54F

Think you should be able to unstake, doing an example.

I think you should be able to unstake:

Please try to follow these directions:

Navigate to the write tab of the staking contract:


https://etherscan.io/address/0x8692e782ea478623f3342e0fb3936f6530c5d54f#writeContract


Click connect to web3
Scroll to 7. unstake
Enter amount 2405351987817
Enter data 0x
Click write
Confirm in your wallet if there are no warnings.


I followed the above steps and it worked. Thank you, very much appreciated.

Brilliant, am glad you got it sorted! Mark as solved if you can, mainly for others with similar issue and to not leave dangling open.
